# Run VS2022 and VS2019 without affecting environment variables

Tags: visual-studio

How can I run VS20022 and VS2019 on the same computer without breaking my environment, I want to use VS2022 on my current project but it messes my build because it has a project which is not supported in VS2022(I think is SQL Server Integration Services Projects  type of project).

So I want to use the VS2022 for dev stuff and VS2019 just for building the solution.

The problem is that VS2022 isn't added to the environment variables path and somehow it is picked in the build scripts, and I don't understand how to remove it, and I was not able to find any other solutions.

Comment: Are you using `dotnet` to build or finding an msbuild.exe instance through `vswhere.exe`?

Comment: Yes, looking at the scrips we have the Invoke-MsBuild PowerShell which is using vswhere.exe.

Comment: The problem is that if I change the scripts I cannot commit them to the repository and would need to have them stashed or something.. or I can't think now of other solution because we use them also in TeamCity, and wouldn't want to break the builds.

Comment: I am not aware of a solution where you can open a sln in VS2022 and build with MSBuild v16 (2019). Or do you want to just invoke build scripts on the side where it uses 2019? Is this a custom rolled Invoke-MsBuild powershell module? You can tell vshwere to restrict the version.

Comment: I want just to invoke build scripts using VS2019. It is the standard version.